# How can I have a separate birthday calendar without shoving all those contacts onto GMail?

Tags: contacts, calendar

I have the HTC Sensation XL if that has any significance on the issue.

I'd like to have the birthdays of my contacts show up as appointments in my calendar automagically.

What I don't want is to put all those contacts on Gmail. I don't use gmail and I don't want Google to have them.

I would also prefer if they would not go into my default local calendar so I can toggle them on and off to reduce clutter. But this is optional.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Install my new open source app [Birthday Adapter](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=birthday+adapter&fdid=org.birthdayadapter).

Comment: Cool. If I ever get Android 4.0 I'll be sure to check it out...

Comment: Great, thanks and +1! Also glad to see it is available on F-Droid: https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=birthday+adapter&fdid=org.birthdayadapter

Comment: I'm not certain whether the link I updated with is Dominik's app or not, but the old link was dead, so either this answer is supposed to be get deleted or should be updated. I chose the latter. // Anyone who is reading this comment, feel free to take action.

Comment: Is this the same as [that one on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.birthdayadapter.free)?

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to add the birthdatr into your Google Address book, and that's fine.

The method I use still require to put that info online, but what I did is I created a birthday calendar on GCal. I creates an entry for each birthday in that calendar and set a yearly recurrence. You can also set a reminder for each of them if you want to. And since it is a separate calendar, you can toggle it off or on at will.

Hope that helped or gave you an idea of what you actually want to implement. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [EboBirthday](http://www.ebomike.com/android/ebobirthday/). You can enter the dates manually. It can also import from Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

The only way is, to create a new unsynced calendar in your calendar app on android. But you have to create each birthday on your own.

Comment: You're sure there's no possible way to automate the event creation?